# Wrong file path with WAMP server

Tags: php, html, wampserver

I have my site in this folder:

```
C:\wamp\www\site
```

and the stylesheets are in here:

```
C:\wamp\www\site\style
```

I have this in my index page (which is in the `site` folder):

```
<link href="/style/all.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

but I got an error:

```
GET http://localhost/style/all.css 404 (Not Found)
```

Why is it `http://localhost/style/all.css` but not `http://localhost/site/style/all.css` like I want it to be?

Comment: try removing slash <link href="style/all.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Comment: Try to remove the slash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just remove the slash / before url

```
<link href="style/all.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

the slash acts as a root directory call

Answer (score 0):

With "/" you are starting from the root dir (DOCUMENT_ROOT) and I think in your case this is C:\wamp\www. But you can modify the root dir, or you define it like this:

```
<link href="./style/all.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Because "./" is relative from the current dir (C:\wamp\www\site).

Edit: Ok has been answered and solved already.